# Why can I read a local CSV file and cannot read a JSON file on Spark?

Tags: json, pyspark, local

I have setup a standalone spark with 2 workers and 1 master node using this docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  spark-master:
    image: ${IMAGE_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    volumes:
      - ./apps:/home/developer/pyspark-apps
      - ./data:/opt/spark-data
      - ./jars:/home/developer/jars
    environment:
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-master
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=master
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G

  spark-worker-a:
    image: ${IMAGE_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "9091:8080"
      - "7000:7000"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=worker
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-worker-a
    volumes:
      - ./apps:/home/developer/pyspark-apps
      - ./data:/opt/spark-data
      - ./jars:/home/developer/jars

  spark-worker-b:
    image: ${IMAGE_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "9092:8080"
      - "7001:7000"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=worker
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-worker-b
    volumes:
      - ./apps:/home/developer/pyspark-apps
      - ./data:/opt/spark-data
      - ./jars:/home/developer/jars
```

I'm executing jupyter-lab from my local machine, using the mapped volume 'data'. There are two files. A CSV file and a JSON file.

I can read the CSV file normally from the volume.

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import os
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('big_file_processor') \
.config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true") \
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv('data/big-data.csv').withColumnRenamed("_c0","fake_name")
df.show()
```

The result is:

```
+---------+
|fake_name|
+---------+
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
|fake_data|
+---------+
```

> only showing top 20 rows

But, when I try to do the same with a JSON file

```
schema = StructType([
StructField("name", StringType(), True),
StructField("doc_list", ArrayType(MapType(StringType(),StringType(),True),True), True),
])
df = spark.read.json('data/test.json', schema=schema)
df.show()
```

In this case, the result is:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o123.showString.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 > failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 19) (172.19.0.4  executor 0): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> File file:/home/andre/Projects/Spark/spark-standalone/apps/dataframes/data/test.json does not exist

Why?

Comment: No! Apache Spark(pySpark)

Comment: Apparently, in the case of JSON file, Spark tries to find the file inside the container(172.19.0.4). But, that doesn't explain why it's not happening in the case of CSV, considering that both files are in the same mapped volume.